# Find the flux of the vector field through a complicated surface.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Let $F=(xy,z,y)$. Let $S$ be the boundary of the solid determined by

\begin{cases}
x+y+z\le 18\\
x^2+y^2\le 4\\
x,y,z\ge 0
\end{cases}

I've drawn pictures, and the solid is just a quarter of a cylinder with radius $2$ cut above by a plane, so, to parametrize it, I decided to separate my surface in $3$ regions: the wall, the floor and the ceiling, and came up with this

$$
\begin{align}
\Sigma (r,t)=(2\cos t, 2\sin t, r)\quad &0\le t \le \frac \pi 2\, ,0\le r\le 18-2(\cos t+\sin t) \tag 1\\
\psi(r,t)=(r\cos t, r\sin t, 0)\quad &0\le t\le \frac  \pi 2\, ,0\le r \le 2 \tag 2
\end{align}
$$

Where $(1)$ is the parametrization of the wall and $(2)$ is the parametrization of the floor.

I couldn't come up with a parametrization $\delta (r,t)$ of the ceiling, as it looks to be (from my pictures) a "triangle" with a curved side.

Could someone help me with that parametrization?

Having these three parametrizations, how do I compute the integral? I know how to do this for scalar fields, I just evaluate the function $f$ at the parametrization ($f(x,y,z)\mapsto f(\Sigma(r,t))$)and multiply it by $||\Sigma_r\times \Sigma_t||$ and calculate a regular double integral, but how is this done with vector fields?

Comment: You could notice that this is a compact region in $\Bbb R^3$ and apply Stokes' theorem (specifically the divergence theorem).  Then you just need to integrate $\nabla \cdot F$ over the volume $$\begin{cases}
x+y+z\le 18\\
x^2+y^2\le 4\\
x,y,z\ge 0
\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} 0 \le x \le 2 \\ 0 \le y \le \sqrt{4-x^2} \\ 0\le z\le 18-x-y\end{cases}$$  That looks a lot easier to me.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but unfortunately we haven't yet covered Stokes' theorem.